# ffmpeg overwrites input files when called in a forfiles loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, forfiles

I need to join several mp4 and wav file pairs using ffmpeg.

When I run the command specifying the names of the files, it works well:

`.\ffmpeg.exe -i file01.mp4 -i file01.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k file01_new.mp4`

But when I integrate this call in a forfiles loop, the source mp4 file is overwritten and the output mp4 file contains only the audio:

`forfiles /M "*.mp4" /C ".\ffmpeg.exe -i @FNAME.mp4 -i @FNAME.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k @FNAME_new.mp4"`

I don't really understand what happens before the MP4 and WAV files are joined. Why is the source MP4 being overwritten?

How do I write this script to make it work? Thank you for your support.

Comment: I think the problem is that the given pattern `*.mp4` also covers the output files `*_new.mp4`, so they become processed too; you could try to put the output files into a separate sub-directory: `2> nul md "result" & forfiles /M "*.mp4" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE ffmpeg.exe -i @FNAME.mp4 -i @FNAME.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k result\@FNAME_new.mp4"`…

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried to use a subdirectory for the generated MP4 files. This does not change anything.
The problem occurs at the first MP4 file encountered, even before FFMPEG is called. And it doesn't explain why the source files are used as targets. If we follow this logic, I should have file01.mp4 which generates file01_new.mp4 which generates file01_new_new.mp4 and so on.

Comment: Add -report to the ffmpeg cmd and share a log from one of the ffmpeg execution runs.

Comment: Then do not use `forfiles`, use [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) instead: `2> nul md "result" & for %%I in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~I" -i "%%~nI.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k "result\%%~I"`…

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl. I confirm that this proposal answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me recommend to use [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) rather than [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), because the latter is quite slow and it expands its `@`-variables with surrounding quotes, which could be problematic:

```cmd
rem // Create sub-directory for resulting files, so resulting files cannot become reprocessed:
2> nul md "result"
rem // Loop through `*.mp4` files:
for %%I in ("*.mp4") do (
    rem /* Process current file, together with the related `*.wav` file,
    rem    and write the result into the new sub-directory: */
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~I" -i "%%~nI.wav" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 96k "result\%%~I"
)
```